# SVN Returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: debian, svn, virtual-machines

I followed these steps on my fresh VM (Debian 6)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736/how-to-setup-a-subversion-svn-server-on-gnu-linux-ubuntu

i just realized where `NameVirtualHost`was and configured it to `NameVirtualHost *:443` 
but it did not help.

my complete svnserver config:

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When i try to reach the site outsite the VM via browser i get a 403 Forbidden.

my dav_svn.conf:

```
<Location /svn>
# Uncomment this to enable the repository
DAV svn

SVNParentPath /var/svn/svn-repos

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  # To enable authorization via mod_authz_svn
  #AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz

  # The following three lines allow anonymous read, but make
  # committers authenticate themselves.  It requires the 'authz_user'
  # module (enable it with 'a2enmod').
  <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
  </LimitExcept>

    #Added
    SVNListParentPath On

</Location>
```

should allow external users to access the svn (as stated in the tutorial).

**So why do i get the 403 error?**

the apache error log:

```
[Fri Aug 10 17:51:11 2012] [error] [client my.main.pc.ip] Could not fetch resource information.  [403, #0]
[Fri Aug 10 17:51:11 2012] [error] [client my.main.pc.ip] (2)No such file or directory: The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403, #190001]
```

i added `SVNListParentPath On` to my Location Block and get the following output in my browser:

```
<D:error><C:error/><m:human-readable errcode="2">
Can't open directory '/var/svn/svn-repos': No such file or directory
</m:human-readable></D:error>
```

## Update:

Using `SVNPath` and instead using `SVNParentPath` solved the problem. But i wanted to use more then one repository.

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you added the ServerName in the apache virtualhost block? Chida

Comment: can you post the entire Virtualhost block?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i added it in the original post. i added the servername into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` as it was stated in the tutorial. maybe thats wrong?

Comment: Whata the Apache error log say?

Comment: interestingly it says i dont have an svn in that directory. but i used `sudo svnadmin create /var/svn/$REPOS` with success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you setup a `SVNParentPath` in the apache `Location` but did not provide a repository name in the client.  E.g.:

```
<Location /svn>
  SVNParentPath /my/repos
  # ...
</Location>
```

accessed with client URL: `http://server/svn`

The `/svn` URL is not a repository but a parent path, you would need to `svnadmin create /my/repos/repo1` and then access `http://server/svn/repo1`

If you turn on the list parent path directive within the `Location` block you can list the sub-repositories:

```
<Location /svn>
  SVNParentPath /my/repos
  SVNListParentPath On
  # ...
</Location>
```

Comment: adding `SVNListParentPath On` leads to another output on the website which i edited into the original question

Comment: Can you include the SVN "Location" directive configuration as well please.

Comment: you mean the full dav_svn.conf ? added to the original question. thank you for your help

Comment: the `SVNParentPath` isn't `/var/svn` it's `/var/svn/svn-repos`

Comment: i am not sure what you mean. `SVNParentPath` was and still is set as `/var/svn/svn-repos`.

Comment: ah you meant it the other way around. setting it to svn did the trick. Now i get a `Collection of Repositories`

Answer (score 1):

What does your `<Location /svn>` block look like? It should have an SVNPath or SVNParentPath statement pointing to your repository. In that same block there should be the `<LimitExcept>` block.

Is /var/svn/$REPOS (or whatever SVN(Parent)Path points to) owned by www-data? It should be, or at least it should be readable and writeable by www-data.

Comment: first: www-data owns it (`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/svn/$REPOS`)

second: `SVNParentPath /var/svn/svn-repos` is my entry.

third: the <LimitExcept> block is uncommented/active